# What is the best way to redirect using Meteor/Iron Router a user that is logged in to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, cordova, redirect, meteor, iron-router

I am new to Meteor and am building an app for mobile (with Cordova). I have my user logging in via Facebook. Once the user is logged in, the app must redirect to the next page (which is mapped to '/hotelSelect').

Additionally, if the user closes and opens the app later, if already logged in he/she must similarly be redirected to the '/hotelSelect' and skip the login.
I have used Router.go, which works but when the app is closed and re-opened you can see the login page for a second.

This clearly happens since the Router.go works on the client side.
What is the best way to do this sort of server-side redirect that I need? I've been looking all over the net for an answer but haven't been able to find a good straight up answer. Thanks a tonne :-)

```
  Accounts.onLogin(function(){
  if(Meteor.isClient) { // only works on client
    Router.go("/hotelSelect");    //check if logged in and reroute.
  }
  })

Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (!Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render("login");
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
});


Router.map(function(){
    this.route('login',{path:'/'});
    this.route('currentlyAt',{path:'/currentlyAt'});
    this.route('hotelSelect',{path:'/hotelSelect'});
    this.route('reqHistory',{path:'/reqHistory'});
    this.route('preCheckin',{path:'/preCheckin'});
    this.route('hotelServices',{path:'/hotelServices'});
    this.route('roomNumber',{path:'/roomNumber'});
})
```

[Edit: Earlier, my server threw the following exception since I did not have the Router.go in an "isClient" block, as Adnan mentions below (Thanks!). I have fixed that, but my real problem above is still to be solved!]

```
 Exception in onLogin callback: TypeError: Object function router(req, res, next) {
     //XXX this assumes no other routers on the parent stack which we should probably fix
     router.dispatch(req.url, {
       request: req,
       response: res
     }, next);
   } has no method 'go'
     at Router.map.route.path (app\lib\router.js:9:9)
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
I cannot understand why one would want to auto redirect "/". The meteor way is to not emphasize on the location bar or the url displayed. It is what is displayed that counts.

So, for a logged in user, you can simply turn the "/" into hotelsearch by rendering the correct template depending on the logged on status. 
IMO, redirection is for static html sites. Apps should not use it.

Also, from the sounds of it, you are forcing a logged in user to a particular route. Imagine the confusion of someone who keeps on trying to access "/" and getting annoyed for being auto redirected. It defeats the goal of keeping user informed as to what is going on.

---

Router.go is a client side method. Modifying your code to this should fix the server error:

```
Accounts.onLogin(function(){
  if(Meteor.isClient) { // only works on client
    Router.go("/hotelSelect");    //check if logged in and reroute.
  }
})
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, since it runs on both client and server here it would throw an exception on the server. Thanks! But my real problem is that, when the app or website is reloaded (ie. It goes to '/' again) instead of redirecting immediately it shows the login page for a split second before redirecting. Is there a better way to do this? I was actually trying to achieve a server-side redirect, so the page flash wouldn't occur. Thanks again.

Comment: I cannot understand why you would want to auto redirect "/"

Comment: If the user is already logged in (ie their login is still valid), instead of visiting the login page'/' I want the user to be directly sent to the'/hotelSelect' page when he or she comes back to the app. (I'm checking for if the user is indeed still logged in buy checking if "Meteor.userId()" is null)

Comment: The point of not letting the user go back to the login page, is in fact to avoid confusion. Think about it like the Facebook website: If you type in www.facebook.com and you are not logged in, it takes you to the login page which is basic '/' in this example. If you are logged in, you are taken to www.facebook.com/yourfbname. This makes it intuitive to the user.

Does that make sense? Let me know what you think!

Comment: The example about facebook is not exactly correct. Logging in to facebook takes you to http://facebook.com or if you were trying to access a certain URL such as http://facebook.com/dinosoup, would take you to that. Overall, to reduce frustration, you should not attempt to force user to a certain URL, rather keep him/her to the same URL that he/she originally typed or clicked himself/herself.

Comment: Hi Adnan, let me put it in a more appropriate context of  an app (we're building it for Android). When logged in to Facebook, Twitter etc. if you open any such app, it takes you directly to your feed. The only way for you to go back to the login screen is by signing out. This is what we're trying to achieve.

Comment: I see. In that case, the URL isn't being displayed in the app.